# Change Date format from yyyy-mm-dd to mm/dd/yyyy Derived Column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I have a .txt flat file source. I am importing that into ssis to do some validation, manipulation to generate a .csv file.

I am in need to convert the date format which is in **yyyy-mm-dd** to **mm/dd/yyyy** for certain date column. For example: DOB column has date 1984-03-16 needs to be converted to 03/16/1984. I am using derived column transformation but not able to figure it out.

Any help is appriciated!

Comment: What is the data type of the original column? If it is date, it doesn't have a "format" - that is just how SQL Server is presenting it to you.

Comment: "...I have a .txt flat file source..." Data type doesn't come into it. The OP is starting with a text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say your Date Column is called DateCol

You will need to create three derived columns from that column and than simply concatenate them columns something like this

```
derivedColumns   Expression 
year             SUBSTRING(DateCol, 1, 4)
day              RIGHT(DateCol, 2)
Month            SUBSTRING(DateCol, 6, 2)

NewDate          SUBSTRING(DateCol, 6, 2) + "/" + RIGHT(DateCol, 2)+ "/"+SUBSTRING(DateCol, 1, 4)
```

Your NewDate Column will be in your desired format

Comment: @AaronBertrand 1st three columns are only for demonstration purpose showing OP how he can extract day, month and year parts.

Comment: Even without the other three columns, breaking it up into three strings is a lot of busy work IMHO.

Comment: @AaronBertrand opss very simple solution just saw your answer :)

Comment: @AaronBertrand lol no I would stick to mine                                           (until you go away )    :)

Comment: @AaronBertrand I have been looking for your article about using `Between operator with dates`  and I couldnt find it anywhere online would you be please kind enough to paste the link here :)

Comment: @AaronBertrand I remember you shared it on one of the questions somewhere I was at work at that time so couldnt properly read it but I  cant find that question neither your article so please

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx

Comment: @Muhammed Ali: Thank you for your time to respond. It worked for me. Just wanted to put some light on derived column expression. I have used: SUBSTRING(Member_DOB,6,2) + "/" + RIGHT(Member_DOB,2) + "/" + SUBSTRING(Member_DOB,1,4) as there is no left string function in derived column expression.

Comment: @ChelChabiloGujrati its great if you got it working, actually I havent used SSIS myself for quite sometime, its good that you got it done, but like Aaron said the way he is doing is simpler and better performance wise. My answer has explained you how to manipulate strings in SSIS, but for this particular operation see what Aaron has suggested :) .

Answer (score 2):

It wasn't clear if the original column was `DATE` or a string. Here is an example that demonstrates transforming the date, as requested, for both:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(d DATE, s CHAR(10));

INSERT @t VALUES('1984-03-16', '1984-03-16');

SELECT d,
  CONVERT(CHAR(10), d, 101),
  CONVERT(DATE, s),
  CONVERT(CHAR(10), CONVERT(DATE, s), 101)
FROM @t;
```

Results:

```
1984-03-16          03/16/1984            1984-03-16          03/16/1984
^^^^^^^^^^ date     ^^^^^^^^^^ string     ^^^^^^^^^^ date     ^^^^^^^^^^ string
```

If you are storing this as a string, you really shouldn't be doing that. You lose all kinds of important things when you choose the wrong data type for things you think you need, like format. Validation is the biggest one - if you use a `CHAR(10)` for `YYYY-MM-DD` dates, what is stopping someone from entering `9999-99-99` or `yeah-no-go`?

In any case, this is a formatting job that is much better handled on the other end of whatever is consuming this data. Until it is printed on a piece of paper or displayed on a report, there is absolutely no reason to take a date or datetime value and coerce it to act like a string. Even at the presentation side I question the wisdom of presenting a regional, ambiguous format like `mm/dd/yyyy`. Are you sure your entire audience, present and future, understands that `09/06/2013` is September 6th and not June 9th? Have any friends in England or Canada you want to run that by?

Comment: I think in SSIS then inserting from flat file you CAN'T use SQL syntax... so @Muhammed Ali answer is probably better...

Comment: @Justin Then I'd really question why you want to bring it into SQL Server in this ambiguous string format in the first place. If it's going into a date or datetime column, the format is unreliable; if it's going into a string column, then that's quite simply the wrong data type. In both cases the original format is better (though `yyyymmdd` is best).

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand: Thank you for you answer and nice explanation. Your approach is right. But I am not loading the data into sql server otherwise I would have keep it the same format as you are suggesting. My package will only generate .csv file which will be used by some data import tool. As ssis doesn't use sql syntax as Justin mentioned, I have to go with Muhammed's approach. I am not criticizing you as your approach is right too in some other scenario and apologize for not providing enough information.(e.g. date is in string).